# ArgumentNull_Generic error in UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I am facing a strange issue in one of my UWP apps. I have over 12,000 installs of this application and only few users (may be 5-6 of them) have reported this issue. It happens mostly on Windows Mobile, but also there have been reports of this error on Windows 10 Desktop.

The error message is:
ArgumentNull_Generic Arg_ParamName_Name, source. For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=623485

I am not able to get this error at all, so I have no clue what to even look for. Usually for my users, I ask them to un-install and re-install the app, and this resolves the issue for them. But also to note, for these users, this problem keeps coming back every 4-5 days, and they have to un-install and re-install to get the problem fixed.

Any idea. My app in question is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/series-tracker/9nblggh3slj9

Thanks

Comment: Without a callstack, it's pretty much impossible to diagnose

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue in some of my apps. I am using Azure App Insights so I am able to get a call stack but it doesn't give me enough information to diagnose. It happens on a OnNavigatedTo page event and is nested inside some of my view model code that is refreshing the page. The weird thing is the page takes no arguments or parameters.

Comment: Hello! I work on the .NET Native Runtime and Compiler team and would like to work on this issue with someone still hitting it. Can you send us a mail at dotnetnative@microsoft.com? We'd love to know what's going on here.

Comment: Matt, unfortunately, I am not able to replicate this at all. In fact, only around 10-15 of my users (out of 15,000+) have this issue. And it keeps happening to them frequently. I doubt it is something to do with their phones or machines. Without the Call Stack, I am not sure how I can provide you with any extra information.

Comment: Interesting that this was posted so long ago.
I just placed a beta version of my new app in the store and am seeing this same error for some people.
This is my App:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/groove-aid-beta/9mzhpgvq2p5r

I installed HockeyApp just yesterday to try and get a better view of it and have some info from the Exception Stack but nothing that really helps me:

OS Version:      Windows 10.0.14393.1480
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  System.ArgumentNullException
Crashed Thread:  3

Application Specific Information:
ArgumentNull_Generic

Comment: @BGTurner not shure if this is the same issue, but a "System.Linq" collection is causing the problem for me. The error is "ArgumentNull_Generic Arg_ParamName_Name". code `serverMonitorItem.Members.Where(i => i.ShowAttribut.ShowModes.Contains("Notification") || i.Type == typeof(MoDynamicMember).Name)`. The part `i.ShowAttribut.ShowModes.Contains("Notification")` is causing the error for me. not shure if this helps you...